How to use PyTorch transform to apply the same transform on the input/output image pairs?
I want to build a deep learning model by PyTorch that makes some image enhancements. Input and output of the model are the same size images.
I want to use PyTorch's torchvision.transforms library for data augmentation. The nature of many useful transforms are random, so I do not know how to apply the same transform on the input/output pairs. I mean, the same transform that applies on the input image, must be applied on the corresponding output image.

The problem you are describing is well defined, what have you tried so far?

You better use albumentation  for image augmentation, you can provide both image and mask together to the augmentation function.
Otherwise you can generate randomly the input parameter (like a rotation angle) and then call the deterministic functional function corresponding to it, like F.rotate in this case.
I think torchvision.transforms.v2 can handle it too.
